# multiselect drop down with select all checkboxes

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I have jquery script

```
script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">script
```

Then i have added the multiselect jquery plugins

```
link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /
script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script
```

But i get the error

> $(...).multiselect is not a function

how to add the jquery plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Did you include a function? Bootstrap and jquery goes in the head of your code.

```js
type="text/javascript"
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#select_all').on('click',function(){
        if(this.checked){
            $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
             $('.checkbox').each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
    
    $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
        if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',true);
        }else{
            $('#select_all').prop('checked',false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<ul class="main">
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /> Select all</li>
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"/>Item 1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="2"/>Item 2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="3"/>Item 3</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="4"/>Item 4</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="5"/>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```